80s/90s comedy film involving lovers/ex-lovers/assassins?
During the 90s I remember seeing a comedic film played on network television  which featured a cast of lovers and ex-lovers who for reasons I cannot recall, decided to try killing one another in secret. I seem to recall there being either three or four main characters, plus the assassin. At one point someone hires an actual assassin to get the job done. I'm pretty sure, as a comedy, the assassin fails spectacularly. As I recall the film wasn't particularly dark, but I might be mistaken.
Apologies for the vague description, but I've never been able to find the film and it has increasingly slipped from my mind. Hopefully the hiring of an actual assassin is sufficient to narrow this down.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Any other plot details or descriptions you can give?

For instance, can you elaborate on 'a cast of lovers', perhaps? So there was more than one couple? Did they all hire an assassin or just one couple? Erasable You is a distant possibility, but I'm afraid this is a bit vague at the moment.

Erasable You may very well be it; Timothy Busfield looks familiar. I'll have to take a look and let you know.

I've added a bit about there being three or four main characters, plus the assassin.

It was definitely Erasable You.

This is most assuredly Erasable You, as per Walt's comment. The film features a man, his wife, an ex-wife, and the assassin hired by the first two.

The assassin is hired per the advice of relatives, who had themselves hired an assassin to kill an ex-wife. The assassin in the movie does in fact fail spectacularly. And the whole movie treats assassinations as if they were laughably commonplace, how did the main characters not know? The film manages to be light-hearted despite what would normally be dark and serious proceedings (including some rather bizarre attempts at racial commentary.)

It had a few laughs, but wasn't very good overall. This movie is hard to come by; to my knowledge it only exists as old VHS copies. The film has some serious issues with its audio-track, whose volume varies wildly even in the same scene.

Could it be that you are looking for Mr. And Mrs. Smith? It's a movie from 2005 and the plot of the movie seemed so close to the one you mentioned
Plot Summary of the Movie 

John (Brad Pitt) and Jane Smith (Angelina Jolie), a couple in a stagnating marriage, live a deceptively mundane existence. However, each has been hiding a secret from the other: they are assassins working for adversarial agencies. When they are both assigned to kill the same target, Benjamin Danz (Adam Brody), the truth comes to the surface. Finally free from their cover stories, they discover that they have been assigned to kill each other, sparking a series of explosive attacks.


This could fit but it's from 2005, not the 80s/90s as described.

@ChrisHayes Edited the answer to say just that

Anything's possible, of course, but it seems the OP is looking for a movie about a bunch of couples hiring an assassin, not about a couple who are assassins.

Correct, the characters hire an assassin.

Oh alright. I'll be on the lookout for a movie like this.. Hope that you find what you are searching for.

It might be The Assassination Game, with Robert Carradine and Linda Hamilton, but was released in 1982, and is set in a college.  
